# How to pad empty values in date time aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do date histogram aggregation, there are no zero values if there is no data present in the inbetween dates. For example, after a date histogram aggregation, a typical result would be like below:

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409097600000,
    "doc_count": 2066
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409184000000,
    "doc_count": 7932
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409270400000,
    "doc_count": 9640
  }
]
```

Here as you can see, after the dates 12,13 the data is shown for 16 as in between dates has no data. I want the dates 14,15 to be shown with 0 as doc_count. Is it possible in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this by setting the [`min_doc_count` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count) to 0 and you will get something like this:

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409097600000,
    "doc_count": 2066
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409184000000,
    "doc_count": 7932
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1407974400000,
    "doc_count": 0
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1408060800000,
    "doc_count": 0
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409270400000,
    "doc_count": 9640
  }
]
```